# Add a google plusone button to an android ndk opengl based app

Tags: android-ndk, google-play-services, google-plus-one

I would like to add a Google +1 button to my Android NDK opengl-based app.

The docs say I should add the PlusOne view to my layout:

```
<com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton
 xmlns:plus="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.plus"
 android:id="@+id/plus_one_button"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 plus:size="standard"
 plus:annotation="inline" />
```

But I only have one full screen GLSurfaceView.  What is the recommended way to integrate this +1 feature?  Is there a lower-level way to do this?